# How R Language works

Tags: r

I was kind of wondering,how R language works internally when we type some command..

Say `License()`

As per my understanding,R language is made of packages,When we execute some command,it invokes the Right package,i was not able to find some documentation supporting this..

**Research done from side:**
1.closest i could get is below link
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf

2.I searched using  "How R Language works internally",but i could not get any relevant results..

Below is how [SQLServer executes a query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/) from starting to end ,i am looking to see similar kind of documentation/any pointers for R

[image]

please let me know if you have any pointers

Comment: Have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html, it is not the easiest document in the world

Comment: @NJBurgo: most likely you should turn your comment into an answer, your clue is very precise indeed

Comment: Thanks every one for the pointers

Comment: @NJBurgo I do not agree that you should have turned your comment into an answer. The question is clearly off-topic here because it is (a) asking for an offsite source or (b) is far too broad.

Comment: @Roland:I agree its a broad topic,but i was looking for any pointers and i have added research  as well i have done so far

Comment: @TheGameiswar SO is still the wrong place to ask this. There are R mailing lists that have less strict / different rules about what you can ask (although they still have their specific rules) and if all fails you could ask questions like this in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notion that the R language is "made of packages" is inaccurate. It is made of commands, operators and functions, like other programming languages. Those commands are grouped into namespaces which comprise commands that belong to the same topic. A package provides a set of specific commands (and sometimes other objects, like sample data) grouped into a namespace. By loading a library (there are subtle semantic differences between a library and a package) the namespace of the package becomes available in the global environment, thereby making these commands directly accessible.

Comment: Thanks,this was worth reading whole documentation

Answer (score 3):

On the suggestion of @CapelliC here is a fully typed answer.

The internals of `R` are included in the document: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html

It is not an easy read, but covers all of the detail. My advice would be search the document if you have a specific query...